# Truncated power series algebra implementation

Tags: reference-request, automatic-differentiation, software-recommendation

1) I am looking for references for an efficient implementation and usage of TPSA. What sources exist besides Berz's 1989 original paper and the incomplete chapter in Dragt's book?

2) Are there reliable TPSA packages that can be used in Julia or Python?

Comment: I know nothing about TPSA, but from the name I guess it must be something similar to what [TaylorSeries.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDiff/TaylorSeries.jl/) does; I suggest to check that package out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Julia TPSA.jl being developed at https://github.com/bmad-sim/TPSA.jl. Should be operational soon.